# Not able to run ansible-playbook using becomeUser

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run ansible-playbook from Jenkinsfile with become and becomeUser parameters but it seems Jenkins is taking its own userid "jenkins" to connect to remote host

Jenkinsfile

```
stage("Deployment"){
            steps{
                ansiColor('xterm') {
                    ansiblePlaybook(
                        playbook: 'myPlaybook.yaml',
                        inventory: 'myHosts.ini',
                        colorized: true,
            become: true,
            becomeUser: 'userID',
            extras: '-vvv'
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

I also appended become and becomeUser in playbook as well

```
---
- name: Deploy stack from a compose file
  hosts: myNodes
  become: yes
  become_user: userID
  tasks:
  - name: deploying my application
    docker_stack:
      state: present
```

Jenkins build log

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /path/to/myPlaybook.yaml:2
<x.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<x.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/5493f46899 x.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<x.x.x.x> (255, '', 'jenkins@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n')
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: jenkins@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Even jenkins run with become and becomeUser command

```
[xx-yy] $ ansible-playbook myplaybook.yaml -i myHosts.ini -b --become-user userID -vvv
```

Please advise to resolve this, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the alternate solution. Observed the logs line by line:

**ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None**

```
<x.x.x.x> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<x.x.x.x> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/var/lib/jenkins/.ansible/cp/5493f46899 x.x.x.x '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<x.x.x.x> (255, '', 'jenkins@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n')
```

Hence added **ansible_user** while doing ssh to remote user in inventory file:

```
[myNode]
x.x.x.x ansible_user=myuserId
```

Happy Learning

Comment: It is also evident from this line `"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: jenkins@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password)."` that it is using jenkins user to SSH to the given host

Comment: @Shubham yep sure, though I tried to give jenkins ssh-key pair with remote userid, but that also didn't work, then had to go through deeply and other way... Thanks for your comment though..

Answer (score 0):

The below link could be helpful for you in understanding about become and become_user.

Medium Blog Link [here](https://medium.com/@somakdas/setting-up-and-executing-basic-ansible-playbook-643ac983680) .

And this is the snippet worth sharing,

```
# as bruce
$ ansible all -m ping -u bruce
# as bruce, sudoing to root
$ ansible all -m ping -u bruce --sudo
# as bruce, sudoing to batman
$ ansible all -m ping -u bruce --sudo --sudo-user batman

# With latest version of ansible `sudo` is deprecated so use become
# as bruce, sudoing to root
$ ansible all -m ping -u bruce -b
# as bruce, sudoing to batman
$ ansible all -m ping -u bruce -b --become-user batman
```